# Magento 2: Login customer from external site to Magento website

Tags: magento2.2.7

- I want to login customer from external Laravel App to magento site.
- I have multi store multi website setup (mean every store have separate website)

I try all available ways:

1) By importing Magento OM in Laravel app & try to login like its **successfully authenticating** the customer but on refreshing the Magento page customer not log in:

```
$store = $this->_objManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\Store')->load($storeId);            
// Load customer
$customer = $this->_objManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->setStore($store);
if($customer->authenticate($email, $password)){
    $customerSession = $this->_objManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
    $customerSession->loginById($customer->getId());
    $customerSession->regenerateId();

    if ($this->getCookieManager()->getCookie('mage-cache-sessid')) {
        $metadata = $this->getCookieMetadataFactory()->createCookieMetadata();
        $metadata->setPath('/');
        $this->getCookieManager()->deleteCookie('mage-cache-sessid', $metadata);
    }

    if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        echo $customer->getId(). "----Customer Logged in";
    }else{
        echo "customer is Not Logged in";
    }
}
```

In above case in Laravel controller printing: `145----Customer Logged in` mean code wise I am getting customer session created properly in Laravel App. But on Magento site page reload customer not login.

2) I Also Try LoginPost Method:

I post ajax request from Laravel form

```
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://ie.domainName.com/customer/account/loginPost/", false);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        xhttp.send(params);
```

to this controller same its authenticating the customer and & I get customers id in the execute function after authentication. But here as well when I try to reload Magento page in same browser its not login customer. What I am missing here ?

Comment: One thing more under same magento when I post form from one store(having separate website) to other store (having separate website) on  
 'customer/account/loginPost'   customer can login successfully & diverted to customer dash board but in above through Ajax post its not working.

Comment: I need to do the same thing.. Have you find a solution?

Comment: yes I figure it out long time ago but forget to post Answer

Comment: Could you please help me to solve?

Comment: you have the same scenario ? you want to communicate other application with M2 on same server?

Comment: @FrancescoMineo I had updated my Asnwer please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well The issue is multi site cookies.

In M1 above solution will work if your code base present on same server no issue in it, It will work for multi websites. It will create cookie for all websites & for all stores.

In M2 its not creating cookie for other then base website when external request received. 
It will create cookie for base website. So when you try to login from other website it don't generate PHPSESSION cookies as per authorized used.

So solution is Move Laravel repository/folder into the Magento Base directory, now it will work like a charm for multi website environment.

Answer (score 0):

Create plugins in this interface: `Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface`. It will handle all the cookies/sessions, no need to do this yourself. e.g. to authenticate you could do something like this:

```
public function aroundAuthenticate(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface $subject,
    callable $proceed,
    string $email,
    string $password
): CustomerInterface {
    $customer = /* Login logic here */
    $customerModel = $this->customerFactory->create()->updateData($customer);

    $this->eventManager->dispatch(
        'customer_customer_authenticated',
        ['model' => $customerModel, 'password' => $password]
    );

    $this->eventManager->dispatch('customer_data_object_login', ['customer' => $customer]);

    return $customer;
}
```

Comment: Its second priority to add logic at the moment need to login from external site

Answer (score 0):

Hasan, 
you can use magento api to get user authentication from magento,  rather then creating any plugin.

$wsdl = 'http://testwebsite.com/index.php/rest/V1/';
$apiUser = 'testuser';
$apiKey = 'testPass';

to get token of API call this API (+ mean concatenate the api path with wsdl)
$wsdl + integration/admin/token
with json parameters of

"username" => $apiUser, "password" => $apiKey

To get authentication of user login credentials

API =  $wsdl + integration/customer/token

API Call
{
   "username":"test@test.comm",
   "password":"TEst123!"
}
Let me know if you need further clarifiction.

Thanks

Comment: Please read my question again. I am not facing authentication issue. I have OM in my hand in External App which is supreme.